# 'categories' is an invalid keyword argument for this function , django

Tags: python, django

So , I'm writing blog and I have class Category and class Post

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=155)


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=155)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

When I want to add new post , I have this error

**Exception Value:  'categories' is an invalid keyword argument for this function**

This is what I have in views.py and what should add new post to database

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            post = Post(title=cd['title'], content=cd['content'],
                        description=cd['description'],
                        categories=cd['categories'],
                        author=User.objects.get_by_natural_key(request.user.get_username()))
            post.save()
            return redirect(post)
    return render_to_response('post_edit.html', {'form': PostForm(request.POST or None)},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: How do you import `Post` in your `views.py`? What other imports do you make?

Comment: from models import * 
and a few other imports :loader, Context, RequestContext ,render etc
@xnx

Comment: sax's answer may be the one you want, but your code should work too, so maybe check you're not importing another `Post` class somewhere (i.e. replace `import *` with only the things you need in your `views.py`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I suppose `PostForm` is a ModelForm)

you can save the form directly and have a `Post` instance back. simply use

```
 post = form.save(commit=False)
 post.author = request.user
 post.save()
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

the reason of your error is that you can not add an object to a M2M field until it has been saved

Comment: If you're using `commit=False`, you must also do `form.save_m2m()` afterwards, otherwise the categories won't be saved.